# Every point which is adherent to a set $M$ is either a limit point or an isolated point

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

How does one prove that every point which is adherent to a set $M$ is either a limit point or an isolated point?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your definition of a limit point ?

Comment: A limit point being the point where every neighborhood contains an infinite number of points of M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x$ be adherent to $M$. Then let $\epsilon \gt0$.

Now the open ball $B(x, \epsilon)$ intersects $M$ because $x$ is adherent to $M$. It is also a neighborhood of $x$.

Now two things can happen. Either $B(x, \epsilon)\cap M$ is infinite for all $\epsilon$, in which case $x$ is a limit point, or it is finite for some $\epsilon$. In the latter case, fix $\epsilon$ such that it is finite and suppose it contains another point than $x$, and define $$\epsilon_2 = \min\{||x-y||, y \in B(x, \epsilon)\cap M\setminus \{x\}\} \gt 0\,.$$ You'll find $B(x, \epsilon_2)\cap M = \{x\}$ (it cannot be $\emptyset$ because $x$ is in the adherence of $M$). This means $x$ is isolated.

Comment: Thanks, this was very useful

Comment: @CarlosManere Glad to help !